# Unable to browse or upload product image in Magento

Tags: image, magento

I installed Magento 1.7.0.2 on my local xamp server, but I am new to it and I'm unable to browse or upload product image. Also when I am clicking an image tab, the browsed tab is hiden.
Can you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This issue may be due to an Adobe Flash player (shock wave) cras.  Restart your browser or system itself, if not resolved try updating the plugin.